# How can i send markers to specified position along with point cloud, inside rviz?

Tags: ros, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to use tf2 method to do that, but dont know how can i achive this task with tf2/ tf1 method, can anyone provide me some idea that how markers( in my case lines, vectors, planes, point with specific color, text). Is their another method rather than tf ?
i was sending this marker node to check it:

```
  #include <ros/ros.h>
   #include <visualization_msgs/Marker.h>
   
   int main( int argc, char** argv )
   {
     ros::init(argc, argv, "basic_shapes");
     ros::NodeHandle n;
     ros::Rate r(1);
     ros::Publisher marker_pub = n.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker>("visualization_marker", 1);
   
     // Set our initial shape type to be a cube
     uint32_t shape = visualization_msgs::Marker::CUBE;
   
     while (ros::ok())
     {
       visualization_msgs::Marker marker;
     
       marker.header.frame_id = "/my_frame";
       marker.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
   
       marker.ns = "basic_shapes";
       marker.id = 0;

    marker.type = shape;
   
     marker.action = visualization_msgs::Marker::ADD;
   marker.pose.position.x = 0;
       marker.pose.position.y = 0;
       marker.pose.position.z = 0;
       marker.pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
       marker.pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
       marker.pose.orientation.z = 0.0;
       marker.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
   
           // Set the scale of the marker -- 1x1x1 here means 1m on a side
           marker.scale.x = 1.0;
           marker.scale.y = 1.0;
           marker.scale.z = 1.0;

   
       // Set the color -- be sure to set alpha to something non-zero!
       marker.color.r = 0.0f;
       marker.color.g = 1.0f;
       marker.color.b = 0.0f;
       marker.color.a = 1.0;
   
       marker.lifetime = ros::Duration();
   
       // Publish the marker
       while (marker_pub.getNumSubscribers() < 1)
       {
         if (!ros::ok())
         {
           return 0;
         }
         ROS_WARN_ONCE("Please create a subscriber to the marker");
         sleep(1);
       }
       marker_pub.publish(marker);
   
       // Cycle between different shapes
       switch (shape)
       {
       case visualization_msgs::Marker::CUBE:
         shape = visualization_msgs::Marker::SPHERE;
        break;
      case visualization_msgs::Marker::SPHERE:
        shape = visualization_msgs::Marker::ARROW;
        break;
      case visualization_msgs::Marker::ARROW:
        shape = visualization_msgs::Marker::CYLINDER;
        break;
      case visualization_msgs::Marker::CYLINDER:
        shape = visualization_msgs::Marker::CUBE;
        break;
      }
  
      r.sleep();
    }
  }
```

Inside the rviz i put /my_frame than i could see the markers, but at same time point cloud cant be visualized, how sould i visualize point cloud along with markers?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239011/how-can-i-send-markers-to-specified-position-along-with-point-cloud,-inside-rviz-?/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2016-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to publish a specific marker message.  You code needs to define the type and location of the markers, and publish them to a topic.

http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/visualization_msgs/html/msg/Marker.html

http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/visualization_msgs/html/msg/MarkerArray.html

---

Originally posted by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) with karma: 476 on 2016-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-07-07**:
ok but after sending the marker topic, how to visualize it at the same time point cloud is been displaying? I added the marker topic = visualization,but it needs fixed frame to be `my frame`and when i do that i cant visualize cloud at same time how to solve this, how to visualize both at same time?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-07-07**:
Define the marker in the same frame as the cloud?

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-07-07**:
How can i do that ? is using tf neccesary for this task?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-07-07**:
Set `header.frame_id` in the marker message to the correct frame ID.

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-07-07**:
o god now it is working, yes, im feeling very happy now. thank u for your support.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-07-07**:
Please accept the answer of @dcconner, so others will know it works.